# With FSharp.Data any way to convert JsonValue to JsonProvider type?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I know I can go through serializing to a string and back to json provider type.  I prefer a cleaner solution. It is small http framework that the user get a JsonValue and might want to use a typed version using JsonProvider.

Something like:

```
type Balance = JsonProvider<"""{"balance":100}""">

let value = JsonValue.parse<"""{"balance":100}""">

let typed = Balance.fromValue value
```

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/1309